# Svg path circle arc subtraction

Tags: svg

I am trying to create an svg path to display moon phases.
The final result I am trying to achieve is something like this
http://ivantacca.altervista.org/arcs.jpg

I have already made the first two svgs but I dont know how to make the third one, in which the first arch seems to subtract the second one.
I supposed the first arc to have a negative value on the x axis.
Can someone help me?

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200">
   <path 
      d="
      M 100, 100
      m 0,-75
      a 0.5,1 0 1,0 0,150
      a 1,1 0 1,0 0,-150
      "
      />
</svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200">
   <path 
      d="
      M 100, 100
      m 0,-75
      a 0,1 0 1,0 0,150
      a 1,1 0 1,0 0,-150
      "
      />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set the sweep flag to 1 compared to the gibbous moon so the arc goes the other way.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200">
   <path 
      d="
      M 100, 25
      a 0.5,1 0 1,1 0,150
      a 1,1 0 1,0 0,-150
      "
      />
</svg>
```